# why i can't show data i want when user clicks on button

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

i am making a simple search autocomplete app which search cities and it's information.

the problem is when clicked on suggestion i want that cities information in different html element.

so my javascript code is:

```
let search=document.getElementById("search");
let searchlist=document.getElementById("searchlist");
search.addEventListener("input",()=>searchcities(search.value));

const searchcities=async searchtext=>{
    var res= await fetch("in.json");
    const cities=await res.json();
    
    
    let matches=cities.filter(city=>{
        const regex=new RegExp(`^${searchtext}`,'gi');
        return city.city.match(regex);
    });
    if(searchtext.length===0){
        matches=[];
        searchlist.innerHTML="";
    }
    outputHTML(matches);
};
function outputHTML(matches){
    if(matches.length>0){
        const html=matches.map(match=>`
        <button class="card" >
        <h4>${match.city}<span class="state ">(${match.admin})</span></h4>
        <small>Latitude: ${match.lat}<br>longitude:${match.lng}</small>
        </button>
        `).join("");
        searchlist.innerHTML=html;
        document.querySelector(".card").addEventListener("click",showresult)
        function showresult(match){
            let result=document.querySelector("#finalresult");
            const show=`
            <div class="result">
            <h4>${match.city}<span class="state ">(match.admin})</span></h4>
            <small>Latitude: ${match.lat}<br>longitude:${match.lng}</small>
            </div>
            `;
            result.innerHTML=show;
            console.log(result);
        }
        }
    
}
```

i want this function to work :

```
function showresult(match){
            let result=document.querySelector("#finalresult");
            const show=`
            <div class="result">
            <h4>${match.city}<span class="state ">(match.admin})</span></h4>
            <small>Latitude: ${match.lat}<br>longitude:${match.lng}</small>
            </div>
            `;
            result.innerHTML=show;
            console.log(result);
        }
        }
```

but it is giving me undefined data. I don't know what to do  .

the structure of json file is like this:

{
"city": "Mumbai",
"admin": "Maharashtra",
"country": "India",
"population_proper": "12691836",
"iso2": "IN",
"capital": "admin",
"lat": "18.987807",
"lng": "72.836447",
"population": "18978000"
}

thanks for helping.

Comment: Please include a json example into it.

Comment: What undefined data?

Comment: @PaulT. undefined is the values.like name of city,admin etc.

Comment: There are some typo's in showresult (match.admin line) but this is not the reason why your code return undefined. The issue lies within another part of your function. If you just unit test your code you will notice it comes up with the correct values (outside the typo than): ``showresult({"city": "Mumbai", "admin": "Maharashtra", "country": "India", "population_proper": "12691836", "iso2": "IN", "capital": "admin", "lat": "18.987807", "lng": "72.836447", "population": "18978000"});``

Comment: question how did you test your code? Are your using an IDE or did you setup your local host correctly. A fetch request needs rights to import json files.

Comment: @JensIngels i am using live server extention in visual studio code and i didn't understand your method to find error.can you explain and sorry for my lack of knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it yourself to complex for what it actually is. Have you thought about data attributes? Here's an example:

```js
//Fetch function
const searchCities = async searchText => {
    if(searchText == null) return;

    let matches;
    if(searchText.length < 1) matches = []; //current behaviour will set it to no matches when your removed everything from the input
    else {
        const res = await fetch('js/in.json');
        const cities = await res.json();
        
        matches = await cities.filter(city=>{
            const regex=new RegExp(`^${searchText}`,'gi');
            return city.city.match(regex);
        });
    }

    outputHTML(matches);

};

//Inner function
const outputHTML = (matches) => {
    if(matches == null) return;

    let html = '<p>no matches</p>';
    if(matches.length !== 0) {
        html = matches.map(match => `
        <button class="card" data-city="${match.city}" data-admin="${match.admin}" data-lat="${match.lat}" data-lng="${match.lng}">
        <h4>${match.city}<span class="state ">(${match.admin})</span></h4>
        <small>Latitude: ${match.lat}<br>longitude:${match.lng}</small>
        </button>
        `).join('');
    }

    const searchlist = document.getElementById("searchlist");
    searchlist.innerHTML = html;

    const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
    cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener("click", showResult));
};

//Click card function
const showResult = (event) => {
    const card = event.currentTarget;
    const result = document.querySelector('#finalresult');
    const cardData = card.dataset;

    const show = `
        <div class="result">
            <h4>${cardData.city}<span class=""state">${cardData.admin}</span></h4>
            <small>Latidude: ${cardData.lat}<br>longitude:${cardData.lng}</small>
        </div>
    `;
    result.innerHTML = show;
};

//Setup
const setup = () => {
    const search = document.getElementById("search");
    search.addEventListener("input",()=>searchCities(search.value));
};

//Load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Indian cities</title>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="indian-flag">
    <div class="1"></div>
    <div class="2"></div>
    <div class="3"></div>
</div>
<div class="head">CITIES lookup</div>
<input type="text" name="" id="search" class="input" placeholder="Enter city name...">
<div id="searchlist"></div>
<div id="finalresult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't have indepth knowledge of data-attributes,can suggest resources for learning this topic?thank you for the help.

Comment: data-attributes are just some sugar on top of normal attributes (basically it just reduces your code size) An example: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3okprs/ . For more info just go to the official documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset

Comment: Something else to note when you're dealing with fetch requests. It might be a good idea to implement a debounce to prevent pulling many requests to the server. Here's an example with debounce implemented: https://jsfiddle.net/9j3okprs/2/